# Slow performance copying large file over network (scp)

Tags: linux, performance, linux-networking

I have a Linux box that I use as a file server.  I have a monthly cron job that tars up the contents of the data drive and then copies it via scp to another machine for safe keeping.  The resulting tarball is around 300GB in size, and it normally takes about a day and a half to complete the copy (over an 802.11g Wi-Fi connection).

Today I noticed that my backup job hadn't completed yet, and it's been running for 3 days.  Checking the destination machine, I could see that only about a third of the data has been copied so far, and it appears to be growing at a rate of < 300KB/sec.

Using `iperf` between the two machines, I can see that my network throughput is around 20Mbits/sec, which is about what I expect over an 802.11g connection.

Using `dd if=srcfile of=/dev/null` on the source machine, I can read about 45MB/sec from the source drive (an external USB drive).

using `dd if=/dev/zero of=/destdrive/tmp.dat` on the destination machine, I can write about 30MB/sec to the destination drive (internal SATA drive).  Seems kind of slow for a SATA drive, but not unreasonably slow (and certainly not 300KB/sec slow).

So I seem to have ruled out network throughput and drive throughput at both ends, so where else can I look to find the source of the bottleneck?

Comment: It seems a network related problem. Try to transfer a test file (say 1GB) preferably with another protocol and measure transfer speed.

Comment: I did that with `iperf`, which shows a 20Mbps throughput - about what you'd expect over an 802.11g link.

Comment: That is pretty slow for writes on the destination drive, even for a single sata spindle. Check the health of that disk using something like `smartctl -a /dev/sd[X]` to see if you have any pending or offline uncorrectable sectors, or if you have any read failures.

Comment: @SmallLoanOf1M:  This is a dinosaur machine with a SATA I interface, so the 30MB/sec write speed doesn't concern me too much.  The kind of throughput I'm seeing is in the KB/sec range, so it doesn't seem like the drive is the bottleneck... that said, no errors on the drive that I can see.

Answer (score 9):

Why you are using `scp` for copying large files in the first place? `scp` has its own overhead (encryption, authenticity checking, etc).

You can use `rsync` (rsync is very well suited for transferring large files over ssh because it is able to continue transfers that were interrupted due to some reason. Since it uses hash functions to detect equal file blocks the continue feature is quite robust.) or some other tool.

Please see this post. [Copying large files over network , faster](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/48399/fast-way-to-copy-a-large-file-on-a-lan)

If you want to use scp anyway , then you should use `traceroute` and `tcpdump` and `iftop`to see the packets from source to destination. May be you find something unusual.

Comment: Fair enough.  But this backup script has been running for years using scp, and completing in a day and a half (which is perfectly acceptable to me, as it's just an unattended backup job that runs in the background once a month).  I'm looking for tools to diagnose what the bottleneck is, because something seems to have changed.

Comment: rsync is your answer if you ask me.

Comment: can you traceroute from sender to reciever and confirm that the path is what is expected to be

Comment: Plus , can you try `scp` with compression enabled. see `man scp`

Comment: answer updated.

Comment: Even better is LFTP+SFTP.  You can spawn many threads for batches of files, or even per file and you get the added benefit of supporting a chroot SFTP only login, should you so desire.  The mirror sub-system of LFTP supports nearly all rsync features.  Your only limit will be bandwidth.

Comment: Running traceroute from the sending machine to the receiving machine shows 30 hops of * * *.  Going the other way shows one hop through the router, as expected.  This might be a clue.  I am able to ssh in either direction, so there is connectivity between the machines, but traceroute doesn't seem to know it.

Comment: so in this case u should check firewall configurations on both the ends and in the network as well. also , DNS configuration for ssh ( used by scp) can make things slow. see http://linux-tips.com/t/disabling-reverse-dns-lookups-in-ssh/222/4

Comment: also try `scp` in verbose mode to get some more info. `scp -v`

Answer (score 2):

Check to make sure -l option is not enabled to limit the bandwidth. Also, it looks like there is a -v will give insight to what is going on for the next run.

> Verbose mode. Causes scp and ssh(1) to print debugging messages about their progress. This is helpful in debugging connection, authentication, and configuration problems.

This has been answered before. Quote from the answer.

> scp is using interactive terminal in order to print that fancy progress bar. Printing that output to a file does not make sense at all, so scp detects when its output is redirected to somewhere else other than a terminal and does disable this output.

Full answer

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3890809/bash-stdout-redirect-of-commands-like-scp

SCP man page

https://linux.die.net/man/1/scp

Answer (score 0):

I also encountered slow SCP performance while coping files ~150-300KiB/s instead of 10MiB/s. Also I noticed that on target server 1 CPU core was busy 100% while I was coping a file. I googled a bit and found [proposal](https://winscp.net/forum/viewtopic.php?t=25705): disable "Optimize connection buffer size" in SCP connection options. It helped. After disabling this option speed increased to expected network level, CPU load on server significatly reduced.